# Cocoapods use_frameworks! causes link errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods-1.2

I want to use some Swift pods in my Object-C app, so I add `use_frameworks!` to my Podfile.After that, I run `pod update`. However, it cause many link errors. Xcode show me an error at `#import <Masonry.h>` ('Masonry.h' file not found),
[image: error like this]

I've tried many methods I can find, but all of them do nothing different.

Methods I have tried:

1. Use `@import XXX;` instead of `#import<XXX.h>`.It bring a new error to me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMPZK.png)
2. Removing `Pods.framework` from ***Link Binary With Libraries*** and adding them again manually.
3. Set up ***User Header Search Path*** ,even set up many others.But all of them have no work.
   Appreciate for any solutions or sugestions.

Comment: My project is Object-C,now i want to use swift with new feature

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210249/why-do-we-use-use-frameworks-in-cocoapod

Comment: I want to use swift  now,So I have to add 'use_frameworks!' in my profile.