# Xcode show warning '-pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable ?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

For now I use Cocoapod for be dependencies management but when I build xcode I got these warnings.

I wonder know where they come from and how to fix it ?
Appreciate all answer, Thank you

[My Xcode warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m33bJ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question - [How to Remove Warning: “-pie being ignored. it is only used when linking a main executable”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789127/how-to-remove-warning-pie-being-ignored-it-is-only-used-when-linking-a-main)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove Warning: "-pie being ignored. it is only used when linking a main executable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789127/how-to-remove-warning-pie-being-ignored-it-is-only-used-when-linking-a-main)