# How to include objectiveC dependency in a swift library

Tags: objective-c, swift, flutter, podspec, google-vr-sdk

Xcode cannot find references to a obj-c library after adding the dependency to my library's Podspec file

I'm trying to write a flutter iOS plugin for the GVRAudioEngine. There are two parts to this:

- The plugin implementation, which instantiates a native object--in this case a GVRAudioEngine instance--and a communication channel to the dart world. Dependencies for this part are defined in a Podspec file
- A sample app that runs the plugin--for debugging and documentation purposes. Here is where a sample AppDelegate class would get implemented. Dependencies for this part are defined in a Podfile

I've been able to include the GVRAudioEngine as a Podfile dependency accessible from the sample app. For this I've had to create a header bridge.

However,I've so far not been able to access GVRAudioEngine from the library side i.e Podspec. I've added the dependecies, and tried creating  a header bridge there, or checking the framework and header paths. I've not been able to get this to work.

Comparing this library to other libraries I do have access to, the only differences I've found so far are:

- This one is written in objc
- the framework is a .a file

I'm close to giving up. I'm a new iOS developer, so I fear there's something super obvious I'm missing.

I've added the following lines to my Podspec file.

```
  s.dependency 'GVRKit', '1.140.0'
  s.dependency 'GVRAudioSDK', '1.140.0'
  s.static_framework = true
```

I expect to be able to declare a field of type GVRAudioEngine in my Podspec library. But Xcode complains that the type is undeclared

Comment: Did you put "use_frameworks!" on top of your podfile? Like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210249/why-do-we-use-use-frameworks-in-cocoapods

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm able to load this dependency from app's Podfile, but not in the flutter library--i.e via podspec file.

I think I'm looking for the same header bridge mechanism when loading the deb in a podspec library.