# Some frames are not showing in React-Native ios Lottie Animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lottie

I am using lottie-react-native and it's not working properly.

```
"lottie-ios": "3.1.3",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

The lottie should works like this:

https://i.imgur.com/MgTJtUw.mp4

But it's working like this: https://i.imgur.com/dk3YUCR.mp4

As you can see it's not bouncing several times. It drops like stone.

Comment: We need to see your code. Please add a [mcve] or your question risks being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

resolved this issue by updating the versions and Podfile.

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.2",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.2.1",
"lottie-ios": "^3.1.3",
```

added use_frameworks! to Podfile in ios folder

Or

```
used this with react-native-animated-loader 

"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
"lottie-ios": "^3.1.3",
"react-native-animated-loader": "^0.0.8"
```

Added use_frameworks! into Podfile in IOS folder as well

Comment: I tried with react-native-animated-loader but it's behavior is same

Comment: And after I add use_frameworks it is throwing error. Apple o-link error

Comment: I updated the versions follow the first answer, and it's not working too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469205/10912727 it is saying we don't have to use use_frameworks! anymore