# use_framework vs use_native_modules

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I do not use `use_frameworks` and `use_native_modules` in my podfile. It runs as usual when I enable `use_native_modules`, but build fail when I use `use_frameworks`.

I've [read to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210375/4311268) what `use_frameworks` for but I'm not aware of the differences between this two.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target "CityWhether" do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
use_native_modules!
end
```

Comment: Did you read the below answer that you suggest? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469205/10912727 It is saying you don't need to use use_frameworks anymore

Comment: Yes I read about it. However I'm still confused why adding it now in podfile will cause error since it's supported by default (Cocoapods 1.5.0 or above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I have understand both the difference (please correct me if my understanding is incorrect),

For **use_frameworks**! [please read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210375/4311268) as it has already describe what it's for.

For **use_native_modules**!, it's actually being use in React Native 0.60 and above for auto-linking. With the command specified in podfile, all the new dependency appended to project do not require developer to append ***new dependency's podspec*** into podfile. It will link automatically when you run `pod install` command.

I have been appending all the podspecs myself ever since I upgraded to RN0.60

Sample podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'example' do
  # Pods for example
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'exampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'example-tvOS' do
  # Pods for example-tvOS

  target 'example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score -2):

the header file search way maybe has been changed, so you can not build sucess