# React has been deprecated - React Native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I am creating an app using React Native and am trying to install cocoa pods for iOS but when I enter pod install into the terminal I get the following warning.

[image: eror]

Then when I try to run my app in an iOS  emulator it crashes and won't run.

Here is the Xcode error.

[image: error]

I am running react native 0.63.2.

Here is my pod file

```js
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

target 'Example' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example


  # pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'


  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'RNCMaskedView', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view'

  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  pod 'react-native-slider', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider'

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth'

  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'

  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'Example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
   

  end

  target 'ExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'Example-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example-tvOS

end
```

Comment: you started to get this issue when you add firebase messaging or when ?

Comment: no, i still have to problem even when fireballs messaging is not there

Comment: you open xworkspace ? try to add the crash you got in the logs to help u properly

Comment: added to my question

Comment: It seems that you are having issue in setting up project dependencies at the first place, especially with firebase. One thing I notice your pod file is missing `use_native_modules!`. You may refer to the this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521779/4311268) which tells you where to place `use_native_modules!`. Once you have it, remove podfile.lock and pods. Then run `pod install` again

Comment: I have noticed that use_native_modules! has changed to use_react_native!, however this has fixed the problem. Thank you for your  help

Comment: How would you use `require_relative` when your ios app sits in a different repo and react native sits in a completely different repo?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't install pod for the correctly target.
This is strange if this is a new RN project because it should take the correct target.
In you recently image added seems like you have another target called AntrimElimChurch so if you want to install pod for that target you should change it in PodFile as well

```
am running react native 0.63.2.

Here is my pod file

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

target 'AntrimElimChurch' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example


  # pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'


  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'RNCMaskedView', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view'

  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  pod 'react-native-slider', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider'

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth'

  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'

  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'Example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'react-native-notifications', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-notifications'

  end

  target 'ExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'Example-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example-tvOS

end
```

After this change run again pod install and it should build

Comment: that's actually what my project is called, I changed it for the purpose of on here

Comment: so in pod you got the correct target Name AntrimElimChurch?

Comment: you did the pod install ?

Comment: yes but it still gives the message "React has been deprecated"

Comment: make pod repo update, delete pod-lockfile, then pod install. the deprecated shoudn't be a problem I think

Comment: After doing this I still have the same problem

Comment: were you able to sort it by any chance? Facing the same issue in 2022